# Safe way to find if we are within a thread bound request without checking for an Exception

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, request-headers, spring-cloud-feign

### Problem

So we have a Request Interceptor (Feign) that checks an `autowired` `HttpServletRequest` for headers, and then propagates/copies these to the outgoing request. Our interceptor's job is to propogate headers from microservice to microservice so that even the last micro-service in the graph has the information about who initiated the request (e.g. tenant).

Sometimes we call feign as a result of an HTTP request thread, and sometimes we call it on start-up or from a scheduled thread.

In the case of a scheduled thread, we would like to be able to detect whether a request exists without needing to do a try/catch. This is the case where we are the initiating party and we don't need to copy anything.

I was expecting the following to work, but we get a proxy object that throws an exception:

The following check fails because this.request is not null:

```
this.request!=null && this.request.getHeader("X-Application")
```

With the following error:

```
No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
```

I understand the error. I would like to avoid doing the obvious workaround which would be something like:

### Current Workaround - clumsy and bad

```
//TODO: Review this
        boolean requestExists = true;
        try{
            request.getHeader(APPLICATION_HEADER);
        }catch (IllegalStateException e ){
            requestExists = false;
        }
```

### Current Code Causing the Problem

```
   public class ServiceNameFeignInterceptor implements RequestInterceptor {
        private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServiceNameFeignInterceptor.class);
        final TenantIdResolver tenantResolver;
        final ApplicationNameResolver appResolver;
        private final String APPLICATION_HEADER = "X-Application";
        private final String TENANT_ID = "X-Tenant-Id";
        ...
        @Autowired
        HttpServletRequest request;

        public void apply(RequestTemplate requestTemplate) {
...

if (this.request!=null && this.request.getHeader("X-Application") != null) {
                log.info("Application header found in the request !!!");
                requestTemplate.header("X-Application", new String[]{this.request.getHeader("X-Application")});
                requestTemplate.header("X-Tenant-Id", new String[]{this.request.getHeader("X-Tenant-Id")});

            } else {
                log.info("Setting {} as {} for URL {}  ", new Object[]{"X-Application", appName, requestTemplate.url()});
                requestTemplate.header("X-Application", new String[]{appName});
                requestTemplate.header("X-Tenant-Id", new String[]{appName});               
            }

}
```

### Current Options

**Please correct me on the following points or propose better options if possible.**

I currently have three options in mind:

1. Use the try/catch solution ( least favored)
2. Check threadlocal variables for the existence of the request
3. Pass our own additional thread local variable that will be a flag ( that we are not within a request context ).

**Problems**

I don't like 1, because catching exceptions are expensive, and because they would possibly mask any real errors.

I don't like 2, because if the spring implementation changed maybe implementation details would change (e.g. key) and our implementation in our starter would break. But in any case whenever upgrading spring boot various minor or major things need to be fixed.

Option 3 I like because it is a conscious action to set a flag before call our feign client. So there is no risk of errors going un-noticed.

### **Opinions, options, solutions?**

### Update

One of the team members suggests we use: `new NamedThreadLocal("Request attributes");`

They suggest this because of the implementation at:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextHolder.java#L50

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextHolder.java#L107

So we would use something like:

```
ThreadLocal<RequestAttributes> requestAttributesHolder = new NamedThreadLocal("Request attributes");
        RequestAttributes attributes = (RequestAttributes)requestAttributesHolder.get();
        boolean requestExists = attributes != null;
```

But this is quite dependent on the internals of spring and them continuing to use "Request attributes".

Comment: "I don't like 1, because catching exceptions are expensive" you would be astounded by the millions of expected exceptions that spring is already throwing and catching. I would completely write this off as a concern.

Comment: @Michael so I would guess the issue is more about missing a real problem... maybe an exception with a request that actually did matter.

Comment: Can you add stack trace of the exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a similar problem and I use `RequestContextHolder` to check if the request is bound to the thread. According to the [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextHolder.html#getRequestAttributes--), `getRequestAttributes` returns null if no RequestAttributes bound to the thread.

```
RequestAttributes attrs = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
if (attrs == null) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: Can there be constellations where we are inside a web request but there are no Attributes present? If so, this my produce a false result.